# Replicate nullreference exception in textbox after clicking Add button

Tags: html, nullreferenceexception, developer-tools, object-reference, radtextbox

I am trying to replicate `NullReferenceException` in textbox after clicking Add button.

Is there a way or a tool to use so that once I am in the page, I will change the textbox ID so it will throw a `NullReferenceException`?

I have tried to use developertools to change the textbox id while I am
on the page before clicking add button but it still recognizes the
original textbox id so it doesn't throw the error.

I want to replicate the issue using the front-end only, without
changing the code, in the functional tester's perspective. Appreciate
your help thanks

```
<div id="divSalesContent" runat="server" style="overflow: scroll;
width: 1017px; height: 680px; padding: 2px">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
               <td colspan="5" style="border-left: .5px; border-left-style: solid; border-right: 2px; border-right-style: solid; border-color:

                  <telerik:RadTextBox ID="OrderName" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Width="50px" 
                        Skin="Simple" 
                        Font-Bold="true" 
                        Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        Font-Size="11px" 
                        ForeColor="#22222"
                        BackColor="#CFFDFF"
                        MaxLength="30">
                  </telerik:RadTextBox>         
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypes" 
                        runat="server"
                        BackColor="#CCCDFF"
                        Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        Font-Bold="true"
                        Font-Size="10px">
                  </asp:DropDownList>
               </td>            </table>        </div>
             <div id="divSubmitting" runat="server" style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 6px; width: 800px; text-align: justify">
          <br /><br />
          <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewOrder" 
              runat="server" 
              Text="Submit" 
              OnClick="btnAddNewOrder_click" />
          <span style="padding-left: 189px">
          </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd ask WHY you have to replicate such exception. To verify a bug has been solved? To replicate a filed bug? IMO such exception is...exceptional, no reason to "simulate" it. It must not happen at all (then if normal code path won't throw it you have nothing to do about it, add assertions and live happy).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes to verify a bug that has been resolved. I just want to prove what's going to happen if for example I have textbox1.text on my page then it was removed but I have a code wich uses textbox1.text,it should throw an error but I cannot replicate it at the testing side. So I want to know if there's a way to change a textboxId to test the issue.

Comment: It'll throw a compiler error when you access the page so normal tests will catch it. To simulate it you have to _change_ something then test is meaningless (IMO).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti have you encountered a nullreferenceexception after clicking the Addbutton?My code is only
protected void btnSave_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  string orderName = Ordername.Text;}

but it still throws an error saying Ordername.text is not found even if it is present.

Comment: Try to post relevant code! I suppose it's elsewhere, such kind of errors (change aspx page but keep code behind unchanged) are catched at compile time when you visit page so it _should_ be something else.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i have updated the description with some aspx codes. Inside btnAddNewOrder_click will throw the error.

Comment: Do you have exact line where NullReferenceException is thrown? I mean are use sure (verified in debug) that to be null is OrderName?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I was not able to replicate the issue but it happens in our application and the error is specified in that specific line. It seems that the Ordername.Text is not detected.

Comment: I can't say without more context (code) but I'd investigate on another direction. I can't figure out any reasonable scenario where Ordername is null. It may be null something else (messing line numbers because of release build). **Anything else** on that line. Even code inside Text getter may be causing such issue (and you don't see it because it has been inlined) but a null control reference inside click event handler...hmmmm....

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the actual error is:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

is it possible that it happens because of postbacks?

Comment: Pretty strange! Problem is if you can't reproduce it then it's hard to understand. OnClick should just invoke event handler, do you have any other code that uses that button? Can you empty your event handler? Can you add all relevant assertions at method beginning (to point out what is null, if not why)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes at any line of your use, do this

```
throw NullReferenceException
```

this would throw the exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx

Comment: I want to replicate the issue in the front-end side without changing the code.